# What's the proper way to write hex literal values in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, hex, literals

In Python I can use string hex literal like `"ab\xa1\x31_\x44\xf1\x10"`. Does Delphi has a similar syntax? I want to define a string that has this literal as initial value. I searched the document but didn't find anything related (The document is not easy to use).

Comment: Delphi strings are utf16 encoded so this literal doesn't look like it makes sense to assign to a Delphi string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix the hex value of a character with #$, where # is the prefix for a character value and $ the prefix for hex.

The string above can be written like:

```
myString := 'ab'#$a1#$31'_'#$44#$f1#$10;
```